# How to update database in moodle using cron

Tags: php, cron, moodle

I am facing a problem. I have to update a field in database by using cron function in moodle. I am using update query in cron function to update value. But It doesn't work. I am using this function to update value:

```
function activitysetmodule_cron ()
{
    global $CFG, $DB;

    $DB->update_record("activitysetmodule",)
    $sql="update {$CFG->prefix}activitysetmodule as asm set status = 1 where exists (select 1 from {$CFG->prefix}course_modules as cm where (module=asm.activityset OR module=asm.activityset2 ) AND completion=1 AND asm.course =cm.course ");
    return true;
}
```

Please help to sought it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Updating_Records

$DB->update_record takes 2 params, the name of the table to update the record in and an object containing the updated data.

e.g.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->id = $id_of_object_to_update;
$obj->status = 1;
$DB->update_record('tablename', $obj);
```

It looks like you should refactor your code to get a list of records to update, then call $DB->update_record on each in turn (or $DB->set_field, if there is only one field to update). Alternatively, you could use the $DB->execute($sql) function to directly run some SQL on the server, e.g.

```
$DB->execute("UPDATE {activitysetmodule} asm SET status = 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {course_modules} cm WHERE (module=asm.activityset OR module=asm.activityset2 ) AND completion=1 AND asm.course = cm.course)");
```

Note the use of {tablename} rather than {$CFG->prefix}tablename and the removal of the 'AS' keyword, as that is not allowed on all DB engines.

Note also, if you haven't done so already, turning on debugging (http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging) will give you much more helpful error messages.

Comment: It means we have to fetch data first like we fetch from select statement.Then we have to update it.@davosmith

Comment: As stated - you can either use a $DB->get_records (or get_records_sql) call to get the data, then call $DB->update_record on the records, OR you can use the $DB->execute function to run a full SQL query on the DB (the first is preferred, as it is less likely to cause problems with different DB engines, the second will probably run more quickly).